# 32k textarea limit in production versus 64k limit in development with CF 9 and IIS 7.5

Tags: html, coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-9

I'm running into an issue where my HTML forms are cutting off the textarea inputs at 64k on development but 32k on production using the same browser on the same machine. The truncation happens when I am entering content into the field, before I've submitted the form. I'd like to get production to accept 64k. I'm running ColdFusion 9 on IIS 7.5. I've looked into the CF settings and I don't see anything there that would affect the textarea limit. Is there a setting in IIS to control this? Or is the truncation happening somewhere else?

Comment: what do you have set under `CFAdmin > Settings > Maximum Size of post data` ?

Comment: What browser(s) are you using? Do they all behave the same way? If I am reading your question correctly the truncation is happening _before_ you submit the form. Is that correct? If so, then I don't believe any server-side settings are going to affect that. Unless your code is written to perform different logic depending on dev versus prod. View the html source code from your browser for the two different environments. Compare the textarea code from each. Do you see any differences? Can you post the code that creates this textarea form field?

Comment: can you paste the code of the page. Including javascript (if any)

Comment: If this is saving to a DB table, the Data Source could have a size restriction

Comment: Have you ruled out browser versions?

Comment: Check page encoding, (AFAIR) UTF-16 will take exactly twice the space of UTF-8